# Not able to put data frame to stata format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

so I am trying to convert a pandas data frame to stata format like this:

```
data_constr.to_stata('/Users/federiconutarelli/Desktop/First_work/PubMed/prediction_ATC/input_dummies')

data_constr
```

is a pandas dataframe. I converted the first column from object to string and also properly renamed columns, but when I hit the run button it raises an error:

````
<ipython-input-454-edfc671f373c> in <module>
      1 data_constr['prd'] = data_constr['prd'].astype(str)
----> 2 input_stata = data_constr.to_stata('/Users/federiconutarelli/Desktop/First_work/PubMed/prediction_ATC/input_dummies')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_stata(self, path, convert_dates, write_index, byteorder, time_stamp, data_label, variable_labels, version, convert_strl, compression)
   2191             variable_labels=variable_labels,
   2192             compression=compression,
-> 2193             **kwargs,
   2194         )
   2195         writer.write_file()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/stata.py in __init__(self, fname, data, convert_dates, write_index, byteorder, time_stamp, data_label, variable_labels, compression)
   2217         self._output_file: Optional[BinaryIO] = None
   2218         # attach nobs, nvars, data, varlist, typlist
-> 2219         self._prepare_pandas(data)
   2220 
   2221         if byteorder is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/stata.py in _prepare_pandas(self, data)
   2426         # Check columns for compatibility with stata, upcast if necessary
   2427         # Raise if outside the supported range
-> 2428         data = _cast_to_stata_types(data)
   2429 
   2430         # Replace NaNs with Stata missing values

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/stata.py in _cast_to_stata_types(data)
    564 
    565     for col in data:
--> 566         dtype = data[col].dtype
    567         # Cast from unsupported types to supported types
    568         for c_data in conversion_data:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5128             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5129                 return self[name]
-> 5130             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5131 
   5132     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype' ```
````

When I type

```
for col in data:
     print(data[col].dtype)
```

no error raises, so I am wondering if I have an old version of pandas.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Federico

Comment: I've run into this as well. I think it's related to https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23633, though you'll have to find which columns are causing the failure for you.

Comment: In case that helps anyone in the future: I faced the exact same error message and found that I had two columns in my DataFrame with the same name. Deleting one fixed the issue.